# CSS Animation webkit transform rotate: why start from 0 all the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rotation, css-animations

I hope someone can help me with this issue, I create a jsfiddle with my example.

Brief: I would like to rotate an "orange dart" in a circle every time the user click on a link.
As you can see it's working well, the only boring issue is that the "orange dart" start his rotation from 0deg instead to start from the last degree.

PS: In Firefox is not giving this trouble.
Part of the code:

HTML

```
<div id="dart"></div>

<span class="btn js_update1">1</span>
<span class="btn js_update2">2</span>
<span class="btn js_update3">3</span>
<span class="btn js_update4">4</span>
<span class="btn js_update5">5</span>
<span class="btn js_update6">6</span>
```

JS

```
to_degree = 0;
var arc_params = {
 center: [218,218],  
 radius: 177,    
 start: 360,
 end: 0,
 dir: -1
}

$('.js_update1').on('click', function() {

from_degree = to_degree;
to_degree = 0;
startChange('freccia_orange',from_degree,to_degree);
arc_params.end = 360;
    if (arc_params.start > 360  )
    {
        arc_params.dir = -1;
    }
    else {
        arc_params.dir = 1;
    }
$("#dart").animate({path : new $.path.arc(arc_params)},980);//end: 0

 arc_params.start = 360;

});
$('.js_update2').on('click', function() {
from_degree = to_degree;
to_degree = 60;
startChange('freccia_orange',from_degree,to_degree);
arc_params.end = 300;
    if (arc_params.start > 300  )
    {
        arc_params.dir = -1;
    }
    else {
        arc_params.dir = 1;
    }
$("#dart").animate({path : new $.path.arc(arc_params)},980);//end: 0

 arc_params.start = 300;
});
$('.js_update3').on('click', function() {
from_degree = to_degree;
to_degree = 120;
startChange('freccia_orange',from_degree,to_degree);
arc_params.end = 240;
    if (arc_params.start > 240  )
    {
        arc_params.dir = -1;
    }
    else {
        arc_params.dir = 1;
    }
$("#dart").animate({path : new $.path.arc(arc_params)},980);//end: 0

 arc_params.start = 240;

});
$('.js_update4').on('click', function() {
from_degree = to_degree;
to_degree = 180;
startChange('freccia_orange',from_degree,to_degree);
arc_params.end = 180;
    if (arc_params.start > 180  )
    {
        arc_params.dir = -1;
    }
    else {
        arc_params.dir = 1;
    }
$("#dart").animate({path : new $.path.arc(arc_params)},980);//end: 0

 arc_params.start = 180;

});
$('.js_update5').on('click', function() {
from_degree = to_degree;
to_degree = 240;
startChange('freccia_orange',from_degree,to_degree);
arc_params.end = 120;
    if (arc_params.start > 120  )
    {
        arc_params.dir = -1;
    }
    else {
        arc_params.dir = 1;
    }
$("#dart").animate({path : new $.path.arc(arc_params)},980);//end: 0

 arc_params.start = 120;

});
$('.js_update6').on('click', function() {
from_degree = to_degree;
to_degree = 300;
startChange('freccia_orange',from_degree,to_degree);
arc_params.end = 60;
    if (arc_params.start > 60 )
    {
        arc_params.dir = -1;
    }
    else {
        arc_params.dir = 1;
    }
$("#dart").animate({path : new $.path.arc(arc_params)},980);//end: 0

 arc_params.start = 60;

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kibray/z02jtcf0/5/

Comment: You should get in the habit of declaring all your variables properly. Using "strict" mode helps because the parser will complain about missing `var` declarations.

Comment: Also, your jsfiddle doesn't work. It requires jQuery (easy to fix) and whatever library you're using to get `$.path` to be defined.

Comment: @Pointy, Thank you for your tips, anyway the script is working at this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kibray/z02jtcf0/4/)

Answer (score 0):

360deg equals 0deg so if you say to start in 360 it will start in 0 and will be correct, the last degree is 359

Comment: I know what you mean, but even change that value I still have the same behaviour in Chrome.